Linking duplicate objects that were duplicated , rotated, scaled before import
So this is an odd one. This started as a way to try and optimize a game map I'll be porting into unreal. These maps are ripped with individual meshes for each object. Many of which are identical except they are rotated and scaled prior to hitting blender. The result is every object in the scene has the same scale and rotation values. I have no problem getting the objects back to their world location after linking but I cannot figure out how to apply the original rotation and scale back. It seems to just use the parent for reference. This script started out as the instanceHarvestor found on github that i've been modifying. My 2 images show my original scene showing 3 objects. They are the same geometry but are scaled and rotated different. You can see that after I run the tool the 2 perpendicular objects rotate and scale to match the new linked parent.This example is just a very small portion of the level I picked because it has 3 objects set close together scaled and rotated differnt for quick testing. 

And the code I'm using right now to try and accomplish this.
    "name": "InstanceHarvestor",
    "author": "BlockyBard",
    "version": (0, 19),
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Object > Relink Duplicates",
    "description": "Relinks duplicated objects based on mesh signature",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy
from collections import defaultdict
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix

def get_mesh_signature(mesh):
    """Calculates a signature for a mesh based on its vertex, edge, and polygon count."""
    return (len(mesh.vertices), len(mesh.edges), len(mesh.polygons))

def get_material_signature(obj):
    """Returns a tuple representing the materials of the object."""
    return tuple(obj.data.materials)

def calculate_edge_data(obj):
    """Calculates and returns edge lengths and edge vectors for an object."""
    edge_lengths = []
    edge_vectors = []
    for edge in obj.data.edges:
        v1 = obj.matrix_world @ obj.data.vertices[edge.vertices[0]].co
        v2 = obj.matrix_world @ obj.data.vertices[edge.vertices[1]].co
        edge_lengths.append((v2 - v1).length)
        edge_vectors.append(v2 - v1)
    return edge_lengths, edge_vectors

def relink_duplicates(context, operator, operate_on_selected=False, match_material=True):
    """Relinks duplicated objects based on mesh and optionally material signature."""

    signature_groups = defaultdict(list)
    relinked_count = 0
    objects = list(context.selected_objects if operate_on_selected else context.scene.objects)

    # Identify objects to duplicate
    objects_to_duplicate = []
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            mesh_signature = get_mesh_signature(obj.data)
            if match_material:
                material_signature = get_material_signature(obj)
                signature_groups[(mesh_signature, material_signature)].append(obj)
            else:
                signature_groups[mesh_signature].append(obj)

    # Isolate objects that need to be duplicated
    for group_key, group_objects in signature_groups.items():
        if len(group_objects) == 1:
            objects_to_duplicate.append(group_objects[0])

    # Keep track of the names of objects to be deleted
    objects_to_delete_names = [obj.name for obj in objects_to_duplicate]

    # Duplicate objects that need to be isolated
    for obj in objects_to_duplicate:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            new_obj = obj.copy()
            new_obj.data = obj.data.copy()
            context.collection.objects.link(new_obj)
            objects.append(new_obj)

    # Clear the signature groups for re-processing
    signature_groups.clear()

    # Re-group objects based on mesh signature and materials
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            mesh_signature = get_mesh_signature(obj.data)
            if match_material:
                material_signature = get_material_signature(obj)
                signature_groups[(mesh_signature, material_signature)].append(obj)
            else:
                signature_groups[mesh_signature].append(obj)

    # Store original data for all objects
    original_data = {}
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            edge_lengths, edge_vectors = calculate_edge_data(obj)

            original_data[obj] = {
                "origin": obj.location.copy(),
                "edge_lengths": edge_lengths,
                "edge_vectors": edge_vectors
            }

    # Redirect print statements to a file
    logfile = open('Instance_Relink_Log.txt', 'w')
    global print  # Declare 'print' as global
    old_print = print
    print = lambda *args, **kwargs: logfile.write(' '.join(str(arg) for arg in args) + '\n')

    # --- Log edge data for all objects before linking ---
    print("---- Edge Data Before Linking ----")
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            print(f"Object: {obj.name}")
            print(f"  Edge Lengths: {original_data[obj]['edge_lengths']}")
            print(f"  Edge Vectors: {original_data[obj]['edge_vectors']}")

    # Relink objects within each group
    for group_key, group_objects in signature_groups.items():
        if len(group_objects) > 1:
            sorted_objects = sorted(group_objects, key=lambda obj: obj.name)
            reference_obj = sorted_objects[0]
            for obj in sorted_objects[1:]:
                if obj.data != reference_obj.data:
                    # Link to new mesh data
                    obj.data = reference_obj.data

                    # --- Log before and after applying transformations ---
                    print(f"\n--- Object: {obj.name} ---")
                    print(f"  Location (Before): {obj.location}")
                    print(f"  Rotation (Quaternion) (Before): {obj.rotation_quaternion}")
                    print(f"  Scale (Before): {obj.scale}")

                    # Apply original origin
                    obj.location = original_data[obj]["origin"]
                    print(f"  Location (After applying origin): {obj.location}")

                    # --- Calculate and apply rotation based on edge orientation ---
                    # TODO: Implement rotation calculation using edge orientation

                    # --- Calculate and apply scale based on edge lengths ---
                    # TODO: Implement scale calculation using edge lengths

                    print(f"  Rotation (Quaternion) (After applying rotation): {obj.rotation_quaternion}")
                    print(f"  Scale (After applying scale): {obj.scale}")

                    relinked_count += 1
                    print(f"Relinked {obj.name} to use {reference_obj.name}'s data")

    # Restore the original print function
    print = old_print

    # Close the log file
    logfile.close()

    # Delete the original objects that were duplicated
    for obj_name in objects_to_delete_names:
        obj = bpy.data.objects.get(obj_name)
        if obj:
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)

    return relinked_count

class OBJECT_OT_relink_duplicates(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.relink_duplicates"
    bl_label = "Relink Duplicates"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    operate_on_selected: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Operate on Selected",
        description="Only relink duplicates among selected objects",
        default=False
    )
    match_material: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Match Materials",
        description="Check if materials match before relinking",
        default=True
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        relinked_count = relink_duplicates(context, self, self.operate_on_selected, self.match_material)
        self.report({'INFO'}, f"Relinked {relinked_count} duplicate objects.")
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(OBJECT_OT_relink_duplicates.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_relink_duplicates)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_relink_duplicates)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register() ```


Do you export to the Unreal Engine?If the layout is to be reproduced on the Unreal Engine side as well, it may be necessary to output object information such as JSON files on the Blender side and process to read them on the Unreal Engine side.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes I export out to unreal. I export gltf with instance data selected. And then import into level in unreal. I have no issue with that side of things. I just need to get the geometry linked up correctly in blender prior
